# Attribute error in while removing an element from linked list element

Tags: python-3.x

Attribute error in a function remove linked list element

```
def remove (head,val):
    prev,curr=None,head
    while curr:
        if curr.val==val:
             if prev:
                 prev.next=curr.next
             else:
                  head=curr.next
             curr=curr.next
        else:
           prev,curr=curr,curr.next
    return head
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Removing the last element? In the middle? At the beginning? Can you post the error?

Comment: please provide the implementation of the linked list that you are using

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
The following methods allow you to remove specific values from your LinkedList of Node elements

```
class Node:
    ...

    def remove(self, val):
        """skip next if next.val == val"""
        while self.next is not None:
            if self.next.val == val:
                self.next = next(self.next)
            else:
                break
        if self.next is not None:
            self.next.remove(val)


class LinkedList:
    ...

    def remove(self, val):
        """replace head with next until head.val != val"""
        while self.head is not None:
            if self.head.val == val:
                self.head = next(self.head)
            else:
                break
        if self.head is not None:
            self.head.remove(val)
```

Comment: Can you answer this in a short method

Comment: @RishabhSharma how about now? :)

Comment: @RishabhSharma then probably you are using lists instead of nodes, we need your code to know for sure